# How to execute javascript code only when 2 DOM events happens?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

ul will display when input field gets some input. Now I want to hide ul when both input and ul loses focus. Same as the stackoverflow search bar works. I tried some options but didn't work. I am sure I'm not applying appropriate method for this .I want to know the functionality for this so, kindly give your solution in javascript not jquery.

```js
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("blur", function(){
        document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none'
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one">
<ul id="two" style="display: none;">
   <li>ajbf</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about a global variable set to true when both events occur

Comment: ID's cannot start with a number.

Comment: ID's CAN start with a number: [id](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)  The restriction was removed in HTML5

Comment: How do you blur a `ul` element when you have an `input` element active?

Comment: @ATD huh... I didn't know the restriction was removed. Thanks for the info.

Comment: np - I've never used just numbers for either id or name as they don't really mean much and can get confusing if you start moving things about.  I only really use them as a suffix to a fixed name string - eg, "list1", "list2" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect in **two steps**:

1. Add the attribute `tabindex` to your `<ul>` - this will make the element focusable
2. Create an object called `pageState` (or similar) which can monitor the state of various elements, including whether the `<input>` has a `value` which isn't `''` and whether either the `<input>` or the `<ul>` have `focus`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');
const myList = document.getElementById('my-list');

// THIS object WILL KEEP TRACK OF THE STATE OF THE PAGE
const pageState = {
  myInputEmpty: true,
  myInputBlur: true,
  myListBlur: true
}

// THIS FUNCTION WILL CHANGE THE PAGE ACCORDING TO THE pageState OBJECT
const checkPageState = () => {

  if (pageState.myInputEmpty === true) {
    myList.classList.remove('show');
  }

  if (pageState.myInputEmpty === false) {
    myList.classList.add('show');
  }
  
  if ((pageState.myInputBlur === true) && (pageState.myListBlur === true)) {
    myList.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

// THIS FUNCTION MONITORS THE value OF THE <input>
const checkInputValue = () => {

  if (myInput.value === '') {
    pageState.myInputEmpty = true;
  }
  
  else {
    pageState.myInputEmpty = false;
  }
  
  checkPageState();
}

// THIS FUNCTION MONITORS WHERE ON THE PAGE THE FOCUS IS
const checkFocus = () => {

  if (document.activeElement.id !== 'my-input') {
    pageState.myInputBlur = true;
  }
  
  else {
    pageState.myInputBlur = false;
  }

  if (document.activeElement.id !== 'my-list') {
    pageState.myListBlur = true;
  }
  
  else {
    pageState.myListBlur = false;
  }
  
  checkPageState();
}

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkInputValue, false);
document.body.addEventListener('click', checkFocus, false);
```

```css
#my-input,
#my-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#my-list {
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  list-style-type: none;
}

#my-list.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my-input">
<ul id="my-list" tabindex="0">
<li>apples</li>
<li>bananas</li>
<li>cherries</li>
<li>dragonfruit</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- `tabindex`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
- `activeElement`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement

Comment: I've spent years trying to understand _Model, View, Controller_ and never really grasped it. If the solution above is a crude example of it, I think I might have _finally_ got my head around it...

Comment: I don't know why replacing document.body with window worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 events just add an click event to all the list items.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const lis = [...ul.querySelectorAll('li')];

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  ul.style.display = 'initial';
});

lis.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ul.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<ul style="display: none;">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>efg</li>
  <li>hij</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No it won't worked, because in your case as soon as I click on ul items after inputting , ul will hide. As I said I want to hide ul only when both input and ul loses focus.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about clicking on the `li` item.

Comment: Clicking on the LI item doesn't give it focus - you have to set its `tabindex` attribute first.  Once that is done, blur should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you may or may not have other items on the page with similar functionality requirements, it might be best to give the input and ul items IDs and target them directly:

```js
const x = document.getElementById('mytext')
const ul = document.getElementById('mylist')
x.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  ul.style.display = '';
})

x.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  ul.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext">
<ul style="display: none;" id="mylist">
  <li>ajbf</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also note that you can not set the focus to an LI item unless you set it's `tabindex` attribute